# golang syntax not able to understand defining variable using type

Tags: go, variables, syntax

```
type ScoreType int
const (
    Food     ScoreType = iota
    Beverage 
    Water
    Cheese
)
```

Can any one tell what does it signify while using in struct?

We can directly use

```
var Kij int = 0

const (
    Food  int = Kij
    Beverage 
    Water
    Cheese
)
```

Are above are same or different??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! they are different .

1. the first one get compiled but second one raises error : `(variable of type int) is not constant`.

you can use the first example without declaring a new type `ScoreType` . but it's a best practice and increases your code readability .

based on your question it seems you don't have enough understanding about `iota` [ which is totally fine ] .I don't think it's a good idea to explain it here because there are a lot of great explanation on the internet :

https://yourbasic.org/golang/iota/
and
https://yourbasic.org/golang/bitmask-flag-set-clear/

these two links will help you grasp the idea behind `iota` and the power it gives you . good luck with them .

Answer (score 0):

The first one compiles, the second is a compile-time error, so they can't possibly be the same. You can't use a variable to initialize a constant!

The first one will assign `ScoreType(0)` to `Food`, `ScoreType(1)` to `Beverage` etc. The value of `iota` is incremented on each line. Quoting from [Spec: Iota](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Iota):

> Within a [constant declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constant_declarations), the predeclared identifier `iota` represents successive untyped integer [constants](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constants). Its value is the index of the respective [ConstSpec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#ConstSpec) in that constant declaration, starting at zero.

To test it:

```
fmt.Println(Food)
fmt.Println(Beverage)
fmt.Println(Water)
fmt.Println(Cheese)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/5rVzS49Bg0k)):

```
0
1
2
3
```

In the second example if you'd use `const Kij int = 0` instead of `var`, it would compile, but would assign `0` to all constants: `Kij` is not incremented on each line. The above print statements will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Htv9F9bPOnS)):

```
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Thanks you @icza for the explanation. I learn something new today. But what type ScoreType int does do?

Comment: @aizen0002 `type ScoreType int` is a type definition: creates a new `ScoreType` type with `int` as its underlying type. See [answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64988768/confused-about-behavior-of-type-aliases/64988906#64988906) and [answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49402138/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-type-declaration/49402234#49402234).